# Why it is throwing an exception when I am trying to send an email by SmtpClient.Send method?

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I am trying to make an email sender by C#. I have used `System.Net.Mail` to do that. But after doing all the thing when I am going to send the mail using `SmtpClient`'s `Send()` method it throws me exception. why?

code is here

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("wtushar_09@live.com", "wtushar09@gmail.com");
SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smpt.live.com");
sc.Port = 587;
sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("wtushar_09@live.com", "************");
sc.EnableSsl = true;
sc.Send(mail);
MessageBox.Show("Mail sent", "done", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

exception is coming from `sc.Send(mail);`

Comment: And the exception was... ?

Comment: The incorrect spelling of `smtp` probably doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smpt.live.com");
```

Your SMTP server name is likely wrong. Should probably be `smtp.live.com`.